# box shadow for simulating top border

Tags: css, box-shadow

Trying to simulate a top border that doesn't start at the left edge of the element.

```
.border-top {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow:  15px -1px 0 0 black;
}
```

The above css is close, but produces a black 15px wide shadow to the right of the div.  How do I contain that?

http://jsfiddle.net/3sjngyk1/

Comment: Where is the border supposed to start then? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top border with just a box shadow?

```css
.border-top {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 0px 0px red;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-top"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a pseudo-element and `calc` (if the border isn't going to be full width - it's not clear from your question).

```css
.border-top {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.border-top::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-top"></div>
```

Comment: the top example does not have the 15px gap on the top left.  The bottom example is intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/3sjngyk1/2/

```
.border-top {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 15px 0px 0 0 white, 15px -1px 0 0 black;
}
```

Put another shadow with the same color as the background on top of the black one.

Comment: the boxshadow goes off the side of the element.

Comment: It does, but with the same color as background, it would hide the black shadow that's sticking out 15px to the right. Only the top 1px black shadow is visible.